# Could server-side data be stored in a variable on the client-side as a JS function is run?

Tags: google-apps-script

I understand that by using `google.script.run` with `withSuccessHandler()`, we can use data from the spreadsheet on the client-side... something like this:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .getUnreadEmails();
```

My question is: Would there be a way of making the data available in a variable in a more direct way like this?

```
const data = google.script.run.getNames(category);
```

Comment: No. google.script.run returns void. See this article. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run  However there is also Templated HTML see this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates which is server side before the page is loaded

Comment: Perhaps you could store it in  localStorage with Javascript

Comment: Thanks! I thought of it, @Cooper, but I actually decided to change the function getting the data based on some parameters. It'll make an additional call to the server, but it's not going to be used heavily, so...it shouldn't affect performance/cost.